# How can I remove duplicates from a union all join query

Tags: mysql, distinct, min

I have a table which holds partnumbers and prices of those partnumbers. This is my main table with about 100000 entries. I also have 3 tables with possible suppliers. Not all partnumbers of the main table are in all 3 supplier tables, and the 3 supplier tables also have a different content.

What I want is to query the 3 tables for the partnumbers of my main table. If the partnumber is found in more then 1 table it should only return the lowest price one. If it is found in just 1 table, return the price of that part.

What I am doing now is the following query:

```
SELECT `table1.partnumber`,
    `table1`.`price`,
    `maintable`.`price`
FROM `table1`
    INNER JOIN `maintable`
        ON `table1`.`partnumber` = `maintable`.`partnumber`
UNION ALL
SELECT `table2`.`partnumber`,
    `table2`.`price`,
    `maintable`.`price`
FROM `table2`
    INNER JOIN `maintable`
        ON `table2`.`partnumber` = `maintable`.`partnumber`
UNION ALL
SELECT `table3.partnumber`,
    `table3`.`price`,
    `maintable`.`price`
FROM `table3`
    INNER JOIN `maintable`
        ON `table3`.`partnumber` = `maintable`.`partnumber`
```

This gives me all the data I need, and after that I check for the lowest price and remove the higher price partnumbers with foreach php code. This is very slow on large sets of data.

I am sure there is a way to only get the lowest priced partnumber if that partnumber exists in more than 1 table, and just return the price if it only exists in 1 table. I just don't have a clue how to query the mysql database for it. I have tried using combination of joins, unions, min and distinct, but to no avail.

Can someone help me out?

The answer from eggyal below send me on my way. I now have the following query which works for me:

```
SELECT `partnumber`,MIN(`price`) as `price`
FROM (
    SELECT `table1`.`partnumber`,
        `table1`.`price`,
        `maintable`.`price`
    FROM `table1`
        INNER JOIN `maintable`
        ON `table1`.`partnumber` = `maintable`.`partnumber`
    UNION ALL
    SELECT `table2`.`partnumber`,
        `table2`.`price`,
        `maintable`.`price`
    FROM `table2`
        INNER JOIN `maintable`
        ON `table2`.`partnumber` = `maintable`.`partnumber`
    UNION ALL
    SELECT `table3.partnumber`,
        `table3`.`price`,
        `maintable`.`price`
    FROM `table3`
        INNER JOIN `maintable`
        ON `table3`.`partnumber` = `maintable`.`partnumber`
) AS `part` GROUP BY `partnumber`
```

Perhaps there is a better way, in which case i'm all ears. But for know I am happy with the above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT partnumber, MIN(price) FROM (
  SELECT 1 AS tn, partnumber, table1.price
  FROM   table1 JOIN maintable USING (partnumber)
UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 AS tn, partnumber, table2.price
  FROM   table2 JOIN maintable USING (partnumber)
UNION ALL
  SELECT 3 AS tn, partnumber, table3.price
  FROM   table3 JOIN maintable USING (partnumber)
) t
GROUP BY partnumber
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT tn) >= 2
```

Comment: Thanks eggyal, your answer set me on the right track. Used solution added to my question.

Comment: @MarcBuurke: Your solution returns all parts, irrespective of the number of tables in which they appear.  Your question said that you only wanted partnumbers that exist in more than one table... or did I misunderstand?

Comment: Yes, you did, or I should have been more clear. I edited the question to emphasize that I need a partnumber if it only appears in one table too.